# how can i get csv or json or geojson from osmnx?

Tags: csv, osmnx, kepler

i want to download map data from osmnx to use it in (kepler.gl)[https://kepler.gl/demo]
but it only accepts data in csv,json and geojson format.

i have tried

```
import osmnx as ox

G = ox.graph_from_place('taian,shandong', network_type='drive')

ox.plot_graph(G)

nodes,edges=ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
nodes.to_file('nodes_.geojson',driver='GeoJSON')  
edges.to_file('edges_.geojson',driver='GeoJSON')
```

but edges occurs error

"invalid field type class:'list'"

how can i get csv or json or geojson from osmnx?

Comment: Please post your error traceback as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: sorry,i have changed